# Angular application suppresses queryParams

Tags: angular, angular-routing

- @angular/core: 7.2.16
- @angular/router: 7.2.16

I am trying to put various optional arguments into the `queryParams` of a route, but for some reason they popup shortly and get vanished again (as I am able to observe in the address bar of Chrome). Here is the setup of my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.paginator.page.subscribe(() => {
      console.log(`this.paginator.pageIndex: ${this.paginator.pageIndex}`);
      this.router.navigate([], {
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
        queryParams: { page: this.paginator.pageIndex },
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
      });
    });

    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log(`params.page ${params.page}`);
    });

    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      console.log(event);
    });
  }
```

which produces the following output in my VSCode Debug Console:

```
this.paginator.pageIndex: 2
src/app/tiles/consumption-report/consumption-report-view-events/consumption-report-view-events.component.ts:142
t {id: 4, url: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents?page=2', navigationTrigger: 'imperative', restoredState: null}
t {id: 4, url: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents?page=2', urlAfterRedirects: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents?page=2', state: t}
t {id: 4, url: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents?page=2', urlAfterRedirects: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents?page=2', state: t}
t {id: 4, url: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents?page=2', urlAfterRedirects: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents?page=2', state: t, shouldActivate: true}
params.page 2
src/app/tiles/consumption-report/consumption-report-view-events/consumption-report-view-events.component.ts:138
e {snapshot: e}
e {snapshot: e}
e {snapshot: e}
e {snapshot: e}
e {routerEvent: t, position: null, anchor: null}
t {id: 5, url: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents', navigationTrigger: 'imperative', restoredState: null}
t {id: 4, url: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents?page=2', urlAfterRedirects: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents?page=2'}
t {id: 5, url: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents', urlAfterRedirects: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents', state: t}
t {id: 5, url: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents', urlAfterRedirects: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents', state: t}
t {id: 5, url: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents', urlAfterRedirects: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents', state: t, shouldActivate: true}
params.page undefined
src/app/tiles/consumption-report/consumption-report-view-events/consumption-report-view-events.component.ts:138
e {snapshot: e}
e {snapshot: e}
e {snapshot: e}
e {snapshot: e}
e {routerEvent: t, position: null, anchor: null}
t {id: 5, url: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents', urlAfterRedirects: '/consumptionReportManagement/viewEvents'}
```

As you can see `queryParams` get modified twice, once with the right arguments and then another time without the arguments. The same thing happens when I enter arguments via the address bar.

I tried the following things to resolve this issue

- Remove all guards from all of the routes (`RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)`)
- I tried to track down where the routing events without the right `queryParams` come from in the debugger (without success, maybe due to a lack of knowledge)
- I checked every `router.navigate` or `router.navigateByUrl` project wide to see if there is some side effects
- Different variations of `router.navigate` with `queryParamsHandling: 'merge'` or `queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'`, `router.navigate(['.'], ...`, etc.
- I googled for more than 5 hours without finding a hint that resolved my problem

I am developing some components as part of a bigger application but none of my coworkers are using `queryParams` and nobody has an idea why the app behaves like that.

Comment: can you reproduce it on stackblitz? So I can have a look? From first glance, I see it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I checked every router.navigate or router.navigateByUrl project wide to see if there is some side effects

I did this again and actually found the problem. So it's resolved.